# jQuery unwrap removing more than one parent

Tags: jquery, html, dom, unwarp

I have an html structure like so

```
<aside class="l-region l-region--sidebar-first">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</aside>
```

The two divs inside the aside do have classes and child elements but for the sake of the question you don't need to know what they are. On DOM ready, I wrap the two inner divs in a new div like so

```
<aside class="l-region l-region--sidebar-first">
  <div class"wrapping-div">  
    <div class="inner-div-one"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-two"></div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I don't use the wrap() function to get the two divs inside .wrapping-div, I create that div, append it to the DOM inside the aside and then append the two inner divs to that new element I created.

When I try to unwrap() those two divs, both .wrapping-div and .l-region--sidebar-first are removed from the DOM. JS to unwrap the elements below.

```
$(function() {
  $('.inner-div-one').unwrap();
  $('.inner-div-two').unwrap();
});
```

I thought that unwrap() was supposed to remove one parent. Why is it removing both and does anyone know how I can stop this?

Cheers.

Comment: Show your JS too, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code is actually working as it is expected to work. As at first instance of $('.inner-div-one').unwrap(); you are removing the parent div and at second instance you are removing aside tag. It is actually removing only one parent at a time. I think you don't need the second statement over there.

Comment: Interestingly, unwrap only removes one parent even if multiple children are in the selection. e.g., `$('.wrapping-div div').unwrap()` only removes one. I thought I'd have to be careful to only select one child, but apparently not. It's probably doing something like getting the set of parents to unwrap, so if they share a parent, it's only called one time for that parent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's as I thought. You call the `unwrap` twice, that's just it.

```
$(function() {
    $('.inner-div-one').unwrap();
});
```

is sufficient because in unwraps both of them.